# Remove patterns from string using bash

Tags: shell-script, osx, regular-expression, patterns

I'm trying to remove some patterns from a file input string (parsing file line by line). Here is a sample string:

```
1: (10/17 12:49:31.175) - CONSTANT ID1 - CONSTANT ID2: RAW DATA OUT     > [0x00,0xa2,…,0x00]
```

And I want the output to be something like the following:

```
(12:49:31.175): RAW DATA OUT : [0x00,0xa2,…,0x00]
```

I have been trying to use `egrep` or `sed` but no luck so far, just keep getting errors or some "unterminated substitute pattern" error. Here is and example of what I have tried:

```
echo $line | sed -e 's/.*\s\([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*.[0-9]*\)'
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm usually more of a batch file guy instead of bash on my **Mac OS/X**.

**EDIT:**

I should mention, I'm reading a file as such:

```
while read line
do
```

Then I want to perform any actions on `line` for every line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also call `perl` from `bash`. The `-n` arg makes it loop for each line. `-e` means the script is one line.

```
cat in.txt | perl -ne 's{.*(.*\().*? (.*) -.*(:.*?)\s\s+.*(\[.*)}{$1$2$3 : $4};'
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what I was looking for. I had an extra `-` in the CONSTANT ID so I had to add another `-.*` in there. Although, I was hoping not to use perl and more regular scripting commands.

Comment: Can I use this output to print to a file now? Haha, never mind, just a matter of using redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '
  s/^[^(]*//
  s/([^ ]\+ /(/
  s/ - CONSTANT ID//
  s/ \+>/ :/
' <<DATA
1: (10/17 12:49:31.175) - CONSTANT ID: RAW DATA OUT     > [0x00,0xa2,…,0x00]
DATA
```

```
(12:49:31.175): RAW DATA OUT : [0x00,0xa2,…,0x00]
```

The newlines in the sed script can be replaced by semicolons if you prefer

---

In a while-read loop:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line" | sed 's/^[^(]*//; s/([^ ]\+ /(/; s/ - CONSTANT ID//; s/ \+>/ :/'
done < filename
```

Comment: This looks good but I keep getting "No such file or directory" error. I'm reading a file like so: `while read line` and then want to parse `line` for each line in the file.

Comment: Or now I'm getting `s/([^ ] ...": bad flag in substitute command: ')'`

Comment: Anyone trying to replicate your approach is going to be in for an ugly surprise if the `<<DATA` they feed `sed` has any shell special characters in it. If you do not quote the heredoc limiter the shell will perform any expansions it can on the contents.

Answer (score 0):

This works on your example input line:

```
 sed 's/.* \([0-9].*)\) .*>/(\1: RAW DATA OUT:/
 ' <<\DATA
 1: (10/17 12:49:31.175) - CONSTANT ID1 - CONSTANT ID2: RAW DATA OUT     > [0x00,0xa2,…,0x00]
 DATA
```

It prints:

```
(12:49:31.175): RAW DATA OUT : [0x00,0xa2,…,0x00]
```